How to open copilot in intellij similar to vscode
In Vscode Ctrl+i opens github copilot in which I can type a requirement.
In Intellij Idea community edition, same thing is not working. How to achieve same feature here ?
I saw copilot: open completions in keyboard shortcuts of IntelliJ but this seems to open copilot chat not in-editor copilot type kind of text bar.

Under "Github Copilot" there is an option:
+ Inline Chat
By default it's keyboardshortcut key is ^⇧G, feel free to assign any other combination.
